# Access to the nested items from a JSON structure with foreach PHP produce error

Tags: php, json

I made this question 3 days ago, but unfurtunaly I couldn't solve my problem till now. I will formulate the question again with the hope that somebody help me.

I have the following JSON structure

```
{"Id":"1","Persons":[{"Name":"Luis","Time":"00:00:09","info":"","Timeext":"","Timeout":"","Timein":""}, {"Name":"Carl","Time":"00:00:03","info":"","Timeext":"","Timeout":"","Timein":""},{"Name":"Ben","Time":"00:00:08","info":"","Timeext":"","Timeout":"","Timein":""}]}
```

To the element `Id` is not a problem to access. I can get this value like this:

```
$arr['Id'] = $_POST['Id'];
echo $arr['Id'];
```

But if want to access to the structure `Persons` inside of the JSON, specifically to the Time value of each Person, I do like this:

```
 $arr['Persons'] = $_POST['Persons'];
    $jsdecode = json_decode($arr['Persons']);

    foreach ($arr['Persons'] as $p){
        echo "$p->Time <br/>";
    }
```

And this is the result that get:

```
<b>Warning</b>:  json_decode() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given in <b>C:\xampp\htdocs\Stopuhr\controller\prozess.controller.php</b> on line <b>38</b><br />
<br />
<b>Notice</b>:  Trying to get property of non-object in <b>C:\xampp\htdocs\Stopuhr\controller\prozess.controller.php</b> on line <b>41</b><br />
 <br/><br />
<b>Notice</b>:  Trying to get property of non-object in <b>C:\xampp\htdocs\Stopuhr\controller\prozess.controller.php</b> on line <b>41</b><br />
 <br/>
```

Can PLEASE somebody help me?

Comment: can you share output of $_POST['Persons']? did you check that you are getting correct input?

Comment: You can add a second parameter 'true' to `json_decode`, that way it will return a associative array instead off an object.

Comment: if you want create json from array use [`json_encode`](http://php.net/json_encode) not [`json_decode`](http://php.net/json_decode)

Comment: Hi! @kakajan I want to convert a JSON structure into a PHP array, for that reason I am using json_decode()

Comment: check my answer, json_decode takes string as parameter, not array, there is example for json_decode, what do you get from `$_POST['Persons'];`?

Comment: check the documentation of `json_decode`

Comment: with $_POST['Persons'] I guest that I can get the second part of the JSON structure. Like with $_POST['Id'] I get the Id, with $_POST['Persons'] I will get a String with the rest of the JSON

Comment: do you call your php code with POST method? What do you send in POST? Do you send form elements with POST? if yes, form does not send json by default, you must serialize form elements with js

Comment: No I don't send a form elements data in my POST I just send data, they come from a table

Comment: can you share code where you send POST data, or share the POST data you are getting in php code by printing it

Answer (score 2):

> json_encode() - PHP Array to JSON

The [`json_encode()`](http://php.net/json_encode) method will take a PHP array and encode it as JSON ready to be consumed by an AJAX call.

```
$myarray = array('Guitar' => 'Johnny', 'Vocals'=> 'Stephen', 'Bass' => 'Andy', 'Drums' => 'Mike');
$myJson = json_encode($myarray);
echo $myJson;
```

> json_decode() - JSON to PHP Array

[`json_decode()`](http://php.net/json_decode) will take JSON and convert it into a PHP array.

```
$myJson = '{"Guitar" : "Johnny", "Vocals": "Stephen", "Bass" : "Andy", "Drums" : "Mike"}';
$myarray = json_decode($myJson, true);
print_r($myarray);
```

Answer (score 1):

You have a syntax error:

```
{"Id":"1","Persons":[
{"Name":"Luis","Time":"00:00:09","info":"","Timeext":"","Timeout":"","Timein":""}, 
{"Name":"Carl","Time":"00:00:03","info":"","Timeext":"","Timeout":"","Timein":""},
{"Name":"Luis","Time":"00:00:08","info":"","Timeext":"","Timeout":"","Timein":""}
]}
```

no comma before Name Louis.

You should always validate your encoded json on http://jsonlint.com/